# How to calculate the probability of selecting only two programs?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given that I have an algorithm that runs through n-elements of programs. At the beginning we start with no selected program, and each time it checks if the rating of the program is greater than the selected program. If the score is greater, then the program which is being checked becomes the selected program. The algorithm runs through all the n-elements and finishes.

The probability of picking only a single program is given by $\frac{1}{n}$. 
The probability of picking n different programs is given by $\frac{1}{n!}$.

What is the probability of picking exactly *two* programs before finishing?

I understand that the first pick can´t be the program with highest score, because that would result in only picking one program throughout the whole algorithm. By how the algorithm is designed, each program is only checked once. So how do I express the probability of picking exactly *two* programs mathematically?

Comment: are all ratings different?

Comment: Yes, all ratings are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first program is the $k^{th}$ highest rated you need the best rated program to come before all the ones rated $2$ through $k-1$.  You don't care where the ones rated $k+1$ to $n$ come in the list.  Compute the probability for $k$.

Now the chance that the first program chosen is rated $k$ is $\frac 1n$, so your result is the sum over $k$ from $2$ to $n$ of the above probabilities, divided by $n$

The probability is then $$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac 1n \frac 1{k-1}=\frac 1nH_{n-1}\approx \frac 1n(\log (n-1) + \gamma)$$
where $H_n$ is the $n^{th}$ [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.

Comment: What exactly would the probability of the above part of the comment be? I can´t seem to figure it out, if you could guide me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

you sequences should look like this:
I assume ratings {1,2,3,...,N}

K rating of first selected program

K| programs with rating lower than K (at most K-1 of them)|N|rest

$$\frac{\sum_{K=2}^{N-1}\sum_{j=0}^{K-1} \binom{K-1}j{}j!(N-2-j)!}{N!}$$ and this is your answer but I don't know how to simplify it